# Want to add an icon in navbar

Tags: html, css

My navbar should look like:

[image]

I want to add bars icon from font-awesome which should appear just on the left of the home link. I tried it many times but each time tried my entire structure of the navbar is ruined as well as the responsiveness.

Please suggest some ideas so that the icon appears on the left of home link while keeping the design and responsiveness constant

```css
body{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #091118;
}
nav{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0;       
    width: 100%; 
    height: 50px; 
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #04111ffa;
    overflow: hidden;
}
nav a{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: seashell;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 50px;
    z-index: 5;
    text-align: center;
}
nav .animation{
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(58, 233, 218);
    border-radius: 10%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
a:nth-child(1){
    left: 100px;
    width: 90px;
}
nav .start-home,a:nth-child(1):hover~.animation {
    width: 90px;
    left: 100px;
}
a:nth-child(2){
    left: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
nav .start-about,a:nth-child(2):hover~.animation {
    width: 100px;
    left: 190px;
}
a:nth-child(3){
    left: 100px;
    width: 120px;
}
nav .start-contact,a:nth-child(3):hover~.animation {
    width: 100px;
    left: 300px;
}
a:nth-child(4){
    left: 100px;
    width: 170px;
}
nav .start-privacy-policy,a:nth-child(4):hover~.animation {
    width: 170px;
    left: 410px;
}
a:nth-child(5){
    left: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
nav .start-docs,a:nth-child(5):hover~.animation {
    width: 100px;
    left: 580px;
}
.search-container{
    float: right;
}
input[type=text]{
    padding: 6px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.search-container button{
    float: right;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    font-size: 17px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgb(58, 233, 218);
}
.search-container button:hover{
    background-color: rgb(35, 168, 157);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 948px) {
    nav{
        height: 300px;
    }
   nav a{
       display: flex;
   } 
a:nth-child(1){
    left: 20px;
    width: 60px;
}
nav .start-home,a:nth-child(1):hover~.animation {
    width: 85px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0;
}
a:nth-child(2){
    left: 20px;
    width: 100px;
}
nav .start-about,a:nth-child(2):hover~.animation {
    width: 92px;
    left: 0;
    top: 50px;
}
a:nth-child(3){
    left: 20px;
    width: 120px;
}
nav .start-contact,a:nth-child(3):hover~.animation {
    width: 110px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 100px;
}
a:nth-child(4){
    left: 20px;
    width: 170px;
}
nav .start-privacy-policy,a:nth-child(4):hover~.animation {
    width: 165px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 150px;
}
a:nth-child(5){
    left: 20px;
    width: 100px;
}
nav .start-docs,a:nth-child(5):hover~.animation {
    left: 0;
    top: 200px;
    width: 85px;
}
.search-container{
    float: left;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 380px) {
span.text{
        display: none;
    }
.search-container{
display: inline-block;
    } 
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
        <a href="#">Docs</a>
        <div class="animation start-home"></div>
        <div class="search-container">
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="search" class="searchbar">
                <button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i><span class="text">Search</span></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: did you include font awesome correctly?

Comment: Yes I tried but the design is getting ruined. The code I pasted above is the one without font awesome. You can copy paste it and try adding font awesome in navbar you will find that the entire design of navbar is ruined

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. For more understanding refer the provided link
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_icon_bar_v

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
}
</style>
<body>



<div class="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i> Search</a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a> 
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```